# how to execute cucumber tests for different users

Tags: java, cucumber

I have some tests in cucumber where the same test has to be excuted for different type of users.I want to avoid writing the same scenario for different users

Not sure what approach I should use. Cucumber is new to me.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at data table: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#data-tables

Comment: Sure thanks...looking at this now

Comment: Seems like the project is using scenario outline ... What difference between scenario outline and data table? Can they be used together?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the (minimal amount) of code that demonstrates your issue?  That's the way to get good answers/feedback/etc.